# List all the nodes with the same menu parent ID

Tags: database, navigation, 9

I have the following menu in my system.

> [image: screenshot]

The parent *menu-link* connects to a node whose ID is 58. All the sub menu-links have a parent ID equal to 58.

I need to find the main and the sub-menus using 58, but I have been unsuccessful at locating the a table that contains that information.

How can I list the nodes that share a particular menu ID?

Comment: Are you actually trying to find just the nodes that are children of a particular parent menu item and do something with them? or are you just trying to display all of a particular menu item's children (whether the child menu items point to nodes or other)?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to get the nodes to do something with them The parent and offspring node IDs will go into some logic else where on the site.

Comment: @sisko did you have a chance to try my suggested answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`menu_link_content`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!menu_link_content!src!Entity!MenuLinkContent.php/class/MenuLinkContent/9.2.x) entity definition contains information related to your question; namely, the database table that contain the parent-child relation would be `menu_link_content_data`.

Below is a code sample that would deliver an array of node ids given a parent node, provided that there is a menu link attached to the node.
This code uses Drupal's APIs instead of SQL queries.

```
<?php

// Get the root based on a given node, e.g. node 58.
$menu_link_root_entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('menu_link_content')
  ->loadByProperties([
      'link'  => [
        'uri' => 'entity:node/58'
      ],
    ],
);
$menu_link_root = reset($menu_link_root_entities);

// Need to call this in order to instantiate the tree_storage service.
$menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
// Get menu link content entities based on their parent property.
$menu_links = \Drupal::service('menu.tree_storage')->loadByProperties([
    // Need a filter value like menu_link_content:8031d182-7a0b-4798-839a-6c66bdd1f27b
    'parent' => 'menu_link_content:' . $menu_link_root->uuid(),
]) ?: [];

$node_ids = array_map(function($v){
    return $v['route_parameters']['node'];
}, $menu_links);
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: This works fine in drupal 9.5 but I couldn't get it to work in drupal 10.1. I get the following error message "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "menu.tree_storage". in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 157 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php)."